# Capacitors current options

Tags: capacitor, current

About capacitors the formula Ic = C*dV/dt refers to the displacement current or to the current which charges/discharges the capacitor?

Answer (score 3):

> About capacitors the formula Ic = C*dV/dt refers to the displacement current or to the current which charges/discharges the capacitor?

The displacement current through the capacitor, and the current which charges/discharges the plates have equal magnitude (at every instant).

Comment: Ah okay thanks a lot!

Comment: But since it is a momentary current, shouldn't something be said about its phase too?

Comment: @EugeneSh. the two currents are instantaneously equal at all times.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy So we can say they are simply equal?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, the only difference is that one is conduction current, i.e. the flow of charges, while the other is not. Interestingly enough, they both induce magnetic fields, as if they were the same type of current.